# Change column width in grid in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have three columns under the row, each column has the cols value as 4. I want to reduce  the width of the "col1", I tried to change the cols value from 4 to 3 but the column is getting smaller than I expected. So I want a cols value between 3 to 4(consider cols value to be 3.5). Is there a way I could acheive this?

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container class="grey lighten-5">
      <v-row no-gutters>
        <v-col cols="4">
          <v-card>col1</v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="4">
          <v-card>col2</v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="4">
          <v-card>col3</v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Vuetify, like bootstrap, utilizes a 12 point grid. It means that for each value from 1-12, there is a calculated width. You can not simply use decimal numbers to adapt the width. If you leave out the width, the column will take the remaining space. Maybe you can specify only one column as `cols="5"`, and leave the other 2 blank? Then the other 2 will both share the remaining 7, making them both `3.5`. Other than that I would say there is no option with default Vuetify components.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Matthias indicated, [the Vuetify grid](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/) is based on Bootstrap but is implemented with the [flexbox grid system](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Each "row" will **always** have 12 equally-sized "columns" whose width is based on the width of the grid container (although a `v-col` element can span multiple "columns", e.g. `<v-col cols="3>`). In addition, there is a "gutter" (empty space, like a margin) between each column, and there is a margin around the row. Therefore the width of 1 column is:

```
one-col-width = (container-width - ((2 * margin-width) + (11 * gutter-width))) / 12
```

If your `v-col` spans multiple columns, then the width of the column is:

```
col-width = (one-col-width * cols) + (gutter-width * (cols - 1))
```

The width of the grid container is either the calculated width of the parent element (the one that contains the grid) or the page (if it is a full-width layout).

In order to control the width of a column, your options are limited.

### Option #1--Change the gutter/margin width

The default gutter width is 24px. You can change this by setting the `dense` property on `v-row`, which reduces the gutter width to 12px. You can also set the `no-gutters` prop on `v-row` which removes the gutters completely. This can make a significant difference since 11 * 24px == 264px.

### Option #2--Set the `fluid` prop on the `v-container`

Setting the `fluid` prop on the `v-container` surrounding the grid will "extend the container across all viewport and device sizes." This removes horizontal constraints on your grid, essentially widening all of the columns.

### Option #3--Use built-in margin/padding utilities

The [auto margin helper utilities](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/#auto-margins) and [spacing utilities](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/) are a set of classes you can add to your `v-col` elements to adjust their margins. For example, adding `mr-4` as in `<v-col class="mr-4">` will apply a 16px right margin. There are also others like `mx-auto`. This will adjust the effective space between columns, but the columns themselves will still take up the same amount of space.

Bottom line, you don't have complete freedom, but you can tweak your layout to accomplish some flexibility.