# Change grid columns in Vue

Tags: vue.js, grid, vuetify.js

I have an outer Vue template:

```html
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <div>
      <v-row>
        <v-col md="4" class="pa-1" v-for="i in allComponents" :key="i.id">
          <gokb-reviews-title-card
            :id="i.id.toString()"
            @keys="addkeyFields"
          />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </div>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

and an inner Vue template (`gokb-reviews-title-card`)

```html
<template>
  <v-card class="elevation-4 flex d-flex flex-column" v-if="!!title?.name"> 
    <v-card-title primary-title>
      <h5 class="titlecard-headline">{{ title.name }}</h5>
    </v-card-title>

    <v-card-text class="flex" v-for="(i, count) in title.identifiers" :key="i.id">
      <div v-if="count == 0">{{ $tc('component.identifier.label', 2) }}</div>
      <div class="titlecard-ids" :class="i.namespace.value">{{ i.namespace.value }}: {{ i.value }}</div>
    </v-card-text>

    <v-card-text class="flex" v-if="!!title?.history">
      <div class="titlecard-history">{{ $t('component.title.history.label') }}</div>
      <div class="titlecard-history">{{ title.history }}</div>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

The row consists of 3 `gokb-reviews-title-card`s. I want to have it 4 cards.

I've tried to change it by adding `cols="3"` to the `v-col` as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387762/change-column-width-in-grid-in-vuetify). This did not show any effect.

Adding a CSS `.grid` to the outer-most `<div>` (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741497/4420271)) can change the width of a card, but the maximum number of cards per row stays 3. The row is "half-filled" then. The CSS I tried is:

```css
.reviews-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
};
```

How can I make the `<v-row>` contain 4 `<v-col>`s thet each contain 1 card?

Comment: Try altering md="4" to the value 3, this attributes takes precedence over the cols="3" if you screen size is over the medium size defined in the component <v-col>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you have `md="4"` in

```html
 <v-col md="4" class="pa-1" v-for="i in allComponents" :key="i.id">
```

if you change it to 3 it should work since it's a 12-based grid

```html
 <v-col md="3" class="pa-1" v-for="i in allComponents" :key="i.id">
```

in addition, your `cols="3"` might not be working because it only applies to widths narrower than the `md` breakpoint.

If you are using responsive layouts keep the `md`, but also define other widths, either through `cols` or `xs`. Otherwise just use `cols`